# Users not saving in my tutorial code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For some reason, I don't think my users are saving to the database. Three of my tests fail regarding signing users in:

```
describe "signin" do 
before { visit signin_path }

describe "with invalid information" do 
    before { click_button "Sign in" }

    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

    describe "after visiting another page" do 
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
    end
end

describe "with valid information" do 
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do 
        fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase
        fill_in "Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Sign in"
    end

    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
    it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
    it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
    it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
end
```

Here is the error I'm getting when I run the tests:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate:
   Missing template sessions/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}.
```

When I type in `localhost:3000/sessions`, this error pops up `No route matches [GET] "/sessions"`.

My config routes seem to be OK:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
```

Here is my sessions_controller:

```
def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        sign_in user 
        redirect_to user 
    else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Incorrect email/password combination'
    end
end


def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
end

def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
end

def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user 
end

def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end
```

I can sign up and sign in fine, but the 'Sign in' link in the header is not changing to 'Sign out'.

```
<% if signed_in? %>
        <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
        <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Account <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      <% else %>
        <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
      <% end %>
```

I looked over the source code, but obviously something is amiss, I just can't seem to find the bug. I also reset the DB, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Let me know if you need me to add more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug seems to be in the `create` action of the sessions controller.

You should do a `render "new"` when the authentication fails

```
else
   flash.now[:error] = 'Incorrect email/password combination'
   render "new"
end
```

When you don't have a view with the same name as the controller action, you need to either redirect, or render another template (in this case, the template for the `new` action)

Answer (score 1):

The `ActionView::MissingTemplate` you are getting is because in your `else` clause:

```
else
    flash.now[:error] = 'Incorrect email/password combination'
end
```

No `redirect_to` or `render` is called, so Rails will attempt to render a create.html.erb (for example).

The `No route matches [GET] "/sessions"` it's because you don't have a that GET route (`:index` will be the one creating this one, but its purpose is totally different). Usually when calling create this is happening using POST.

So it's either the factory not creating your user or your authentication method failing.